Eclipse gives the error "Unable to open file" when trying to run the project
Yesterday everything was working fine. Today I open Eclipse, run Index.jsp, then Notepad++ opens by itself (without anything, it just runs empty) and an error message appears above it:

Unable to open file
"D:\Eclipse (JavaEE)\eclipse\http:\localhost:8082\TastePalette\index.jsp" cannot be opened:
The folder "D:\Eclipse (JavaEE)\eclipse\http:\localhost:8082\TastePalette" does not exist

At the same time in the folder D:\Eclipse (JavaEE)\TastePalette everything is there and such problems did not occur before. Tomcat 9.0 is connected as a server.
I decided to check and created a new dynamic web project. It also can not be started - Notepad++ opens and the same error occurs.
Reinstalling Eclipse and Tomcat (and installing Tomcat version 10) did not help.
What can be the problem?
Really need help, I need to do a term paper on an assignment specifically in Eclipse and it doesn't work, I hope for your help.
(I apologize in advance for English, not my native language)
